Selenium testing an Azure DevOps extension issue where React rendered content is missing
I want to use Selenium to test a custom Azure DevOps React/Javascript extension. The extension works fine, but there are issues when testing with Selenium.
I successfully managed to get Selenium to:

Navigate to Azure Devops and Login.
Switch to the correct page (a tab in Azure DevOps speak).
Locate the iframe element that hosts the extension.
Switch to the iframe element.
Locate the <div id="root"> element of the React app.

However, locating any HTML element rendered by the React app fails. See code below.
Suggestions are most welcome!
        url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_workitems/edit/{work_item_id}"
        driver.get(url)
        print('URL:', url)

        # Click on the 'Test Script' tab
        test_script_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@role='tab' and .//text()='Test Script']"))
        )
        test_script_tab.click()
        print("Clicked on test script tab successfully.")

        # Switch to the iframe
        #iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        #EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.external-content-iframe"))
        #)

        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))
        print("Switched to iframe successfully.")

        # Wait for the element with ID "root" to be present
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        root = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "root")))
        print("root located")

        extension = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-testid='my-extension']")))

        # This element is never found!

        print("extension element located")

[EDIT]
The HTML code with the iframe:
<iframe frameborder="0" class="external-content-iframe" id="externalContentHost7" name="externalContentHost7"
  role="presentation" style=""
  src="https://my-extension.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/my-extension/1.0.135/1720177232664/./dist/index.html">


  <html lang="en" class=" cqcfdctn idc0_350">

  <head>
  </head>

  <body class="m-0">
    <div id="root">
      <div data-testid="my-extension">


Please check if you can find this element in the Developer tool. In DevTools, click Select an element or press Command+Shift+C (Mac) or Control+Shift+C (Windows, Linux), and then click the element in the viewport. If you can, share the related HTML code.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT An edit was added to the post with the iframe HTML :o)

Have you tried to locate elements using XPATH instead of ID? Did it work?

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT yes, it appears that any React generated HTML never was injected at the root element.

Maybe you can try to use EC.visibility_of_element_located instead of EC.presence_of_element_located.  "it appears that any React generated HTML never was injected at the root element." - The rendering has not finished or the rendering has not started yet?

It turns out that another iframe element existed on the page, and that driver.switch_to.frame() selects the first one. The issue was fixed by creating a more specific selector for the iframe.
